# Putting my attendance base on calendar and insert in my database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am making a attendance system , i have a database which is i created and it has a tables from jan-dec (12 tables) and each table has this kind of column (Jan1,jan2//feb1,feb2//mar1,mar2... etc ) i know it is not a good practice tho i'm not familiar with sql, I would like to ask if how would i be able to make a much lesser tables/columns ? and it will based on my datepicker in my vb.net program?

Comment: Yes you can make much less columns per table.  You are ignoring the 'R' in RDBMS

Answer (score 1):

Delve deeper into [relational database design](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/Relational_Database_Design.html) (take the link as a first step).

One thing is to create just one table, and have in it a column of type `DATE` or `DATETIME` to denote the date. Additional columns would have related data that is linked to the date. That would simplify your table structure greatly. From 12 tables with approx. 30 colums, to just one table with one column + columns with related information.